# photoshop alternative for front end developers on ubuntu

Tags: photoshop, css, web-development

i am a front end developer and i just installed Ubuntu
is there a Photoshop alternative for Ubuntu that has the CSS code feature that i can copy the css code right from the .PSD and i also need to export the images from the .PSD as jpeg or as .png

Answer (score 0):

There are top notch alternative software for `Photoshop` like `GIMP` and `Avocode`. I'm not sure if they can serve you what you need.
By the way You can use `Photoshop` with help of `wine`

Check this out: [How to Install and Use Wine to Run Windows Applications on Linux](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-install-and-use-wine-run-windows-applications-linux/)

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP's stated question: "*is there a Photoshop alternative for Ubuntu that has the CSS code feature that i can copy the css code right from the .PSD [?]*"